# How can I give the name of a webpage(like xxx.html) using servlet?

Tags: java, html, jakarta-ee, servlets, web

I am new in j2EE and now learning servlet.I display a simple ***"Hello World"*** string into the web page using servlet.
My code is :

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        pw.println("<html>");
        pw.println("<head><title>Hello World</title></title>");
        pw.println("<body>");
        pw.println("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
        pw.println("</body></html>");
    }
}
```

How can I give the name of this webpage like  **HelloWorld.html**

Comment: How?please show the code.

Answer (score -1):

It may helps you :

```
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>(with package name).HelloWorld</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>HelloWorld.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```